# Button right side of inputs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put the submit button the right side of the inputs but it's only staying left?

Preview: 
http://prntscr.com/37t5vd

I don't see what the problem is, it's really starting to bug me, could someone help me please? thanks

HTML:

```
<form id="loginformitem" name="loginformitem" method="post" >
  <span>
 <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="log_password" class="logintext" id="password">
  </span>
  <span>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="log_username" class="logintext"  id="username">
  </span>
  <button type="submit" class="loginbutton" name="login">Login</button>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.logintext {
    margin-top: 4px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
border-radius: 2px;
padding: 2px 2px 3px 2px;
font-size: 13px;
color: #222;
}

form label {
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #a4c0d7;
}

.loginbutton {
    float: right;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #63b8ee), color-stop(1, #468ccf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #63b8ee 5%, #468ccf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#63b8ee', endColorstr='#468ccf');
    background-color:#63b8ee;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #3866a3;
border-radius: 2px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#14396a;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    width:76px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #7cacde;
}
.loginbutton:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #468ccf), color-stop(1, #63b8ee) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #468ccf 5%, #63b8ee 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#468ccf', endColorstr='#63b8ee');
    background-color:#468ccf;
}

form span {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 10px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  float: right;
  margin-top:-30px;
}
span input {
 display:block;/* if you want submit under , do form input {} to include it too */
}
```

Comment: put your "form span" float:left;

Answer (score 2):

```
.logintext {
    margin-top: 12px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
border-radius: 2px;
padding: 2px 2px 3px 2px;
font-size: 13px;
color: #222;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
}

form label {
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #a4c0d7;
}

.loginbutton {
    float: left;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #63b8ee), color-stop(1, #468ccf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #63b8ee 5%, #468ccf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#63b8ee', endColorstr='#468ccf');
    background-color:#63b8ee;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #3866a3;
border-radius: 2px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#14396a;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    width:76px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #7cacde;
}
.loginbutton:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #468ccf), color-stop(1, #63b8ee) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #468ccf 5%, #63b8ee 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#468ccf', endColorstr='#63b8ee');
    background-color:#468ccf;
}

form span {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 10px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  margin-top:-30px;
}
span input {
 display:block;/* if you want submit under , do form input {} to include it too */
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the float right here:

```
form span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    /* float: right; */
    margin-top: -30px;
 }
```

And reset your margins and paddings to make everything line up nice again.

If you are lookin into floating your entire form right as well, you have to do it in a larger scope such as here:

```
#loginformitem {
     width: 565px;
     float: right;
}
```

Here is [***WORKING DEMO***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aDIxc/)